# whether feathers js client has disconnect function?

Tags: feathersjs

I am using `feathers` + `primus` to communicate with feathers server. Below is the client code to initialise client instance. The connection between client and server will be created on the code `.configure(feathers.primus(primus));`. I wander whether it has a function to disconnect the connection.

```
const feathers = require('feathers-client');
const rest = require('feathers-rest/client');
const Primus = require('../public/dist/primus.js');
let primus = new Primus('http://localhost:3030');
let app = feathers()
  .configure(feathers.hooks())
  .configure(feathers.primus(primus));
```

Comment: Close the connection with `primus.end()` (see https://github.com/primus/primus#sparkenddata-options).

Comment: thanks for response. How can I get the `spark` instance in my client code?

Comment: `app.primus.end()`

Comment: this one works, thanks.